# Cannot Get JSON Data Out Of dataTask in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

First post, so be gentle. I am playing around with getting JSON data in Swift 3, Xcode 8.1. I am specifically getting my data from http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.9782&lon=-76.4933&FcstType=json. My Code is as follows:

```
    private func getWeatherData(url:URL) -> (currentObservation:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, currentData:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    var currentObservation:Dictionary = [:] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    var currentData:Dictionary = [:] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("Error retrieving URLSession")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let JSONData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let observation = JSONData["currentobservation"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        currentObservation = observation
                        print("currentObservation inside of task: \(currentObservation)\n\n")
                    }

                    if let data = JSONData["data"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        currentData = data
                        print("currentData inside of task: \(currentData)")
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error in trying JSONSerialization")

                }

            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()

    print("currentObservation outside of task: \(currentObservation) \n\n")
    print("currentData outside of task: \(currentData)")

    return (currentObservation , currentData)

}
```

The output I get is:

```
currentObservation outside of task: [:] 


currentData outside of task: [:]
currentObservation: [:] 


currentData: [:]
currentObservation inside of task: ["state": MD, "name": Annapolis,     United States Naval Academy, "longitude": -76.49, "elev": 3, "Relh": 79, "WindChill": NA, "Weather": Fair, "Altimeter": 1028.7, "latitude": 38.99, "Temp": 46, "SLP": 30.37, "id": KNAK, "timezone": EST, "Weatherimage": nsct.png, "Windd": 0, "Winds": 0, "Visibility": 10.00, "Gust": 0, "Dewp": 40, "Date": 7 Nov 20:54 pm EST]


currentData inside of task: ["hazard": <__NSArrayM 0x60800005a520>(
Frost Advisory, Hazardous Weather Outlook ), "weather": <__NSArrayM 0x60800005a490>(
Clear then Areas Frost, Areas Frost then Sunny,
Partly Cloudy then Slight Chance Showers, etc.(edited for brevity)]
```

I am getting a JSON data response, but I can't seem to keep hold of the data.

I am confused by several things. First, why are the print statements outside of the URLSession.shared.dataTask printed before those inside?

Also, the print statements of "currentObservation" and "currentData" are called outside of the function, and they print before the ones inside of URLSession.shared.dataTask. Why is that?

Lastly, and most importantly, why is the JSON data not making it out of the URLSession.shared.dataTask block?

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.

Edit:
This is now my current code based on Vinodh's response. currentObservation and currentData are still empty when I print them.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var currentObservation:Dictionary = [:] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    var currentData:Dictionary = [:] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    let serverURL = URL(string:"http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.9782&lon=-76.4933&FcstType=json")
    getWeatherData(serverURL: serverURL!, completion: { serverResponse in
        if let observation = serverResponse["currentobservation"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            currentObservation = observation
            print("currentObservation inside of task: \(currentObservation)\n\n")
        }

        if let data = serverResponse["data"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            currentData = data
            print("currentData inside of task: \(currentData)\n\n")
        }
    })

    print("currentObservation outside of task: \(currentObservation)\n\n")
    print("currentData outside of task: \(currentData)")



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


private func getWeatherData(serverURL:URL, completion:@escaping (AnyObject) ->()){
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: serverURL) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("Error retrieving URLSession")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let JSONData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    completion(JSONData)

                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error in trying JSONSerialization")

                }

            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()


}
```

}

And yes, I know I shouldn't be doing this all in the ViewController in violation of MVC, but I am just playing around trying to get it to work before adding the complexity of a data model and controller, as well as a UI. Thanks.

Comment: `dataTask` works asynchronously. You can't return anything from a method which contains an asynchronous task.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. How would there be anything to return if the take had completed by the time the function call had completed. Thanks.

Comment: The answer of Vinod provides a solution to return data asynchronously using a callback closure. Further there are a few hundred related topics here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

First, the code inside `URLSession.shared.dataTask` closure is not actually executed in the main thread, it will get called once you call `task.resume()` and it will run in background, thus all the print you do outside of it will get called first, since that `task` have not finish, thats why the print `currentObservation inside of task` inside will get called after

Second, you dont use the task's response OUTSIDE of the code block, just imagine it like this : create task -> resume task -> network request.... -> finish code closure, you have to execute the code involve the response in the finish code closure, which is the part that holding the print `currentObservation inside of task`

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I thought background threads had to be specifically called. It was always my intention to make the request in the background eventually. That, of course, would explain the timing. That of course leads to the question of HOW to use the response outside of the closure.

Comment: You dont, thats all, of course you can save it as property and call method or whatever stuff, but all have to start from INSIDE the finish closure, because thats where you got the response, not from anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Your closure are not good. Please change like below to get proper response .

**Service Call method :**

```
   private func getWeatherData(serverURL:URL ,completion:@escaping (AnyObject) ->()){
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: serverURL) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print ("Error retrieving URLSession")
                }
                else
                {
                    if let content = data
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            let JSONData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                            completion(JSONData)        

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            print("Error in trying JSONSerialization")

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()


        }
```

Response parsing:

```
var currentObservation:Dictionary = [:] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        var currentData:Dictionary = [:] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        let serverURL = URL(string:"http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.9782&lon=-76.4933&FcstType=json")
        getWeatherData(serverURL: serverURL!, completion: { serverResponse in
            if let observation = serverResponse["currentobservation"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                currentObservation = observation
                print("currentObservation inside of task: \(currentObservation)\n\n")
            }

            if let data = serverResponse["data"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                currentData = data
                print("currentData inside of task: \(currentData)")
            }
        })
```

Comment: As I am obviously not strong on closures, I had to look up Escaping Closures. That is obviously much more elegant than trying to pass the information back as a return value. What I don't get, and just for my own knowledge, is why passing it out as a return value did not work. Can you explain that? Thanks.

Comment: I tried the code, and it is still not working. I suspect the problem is because of the nature of the closure as a background thread. When I am looking at the variables, the closure hasn't escaped, and therefore they are still empty. So, my question is how do I code it so I wait until the variables have been populated before looking at them? I will post my entire code, but the responses data response is still the same.

Comment: @Yrb the reason it does not return the value is because at the time that the return line is hit the value does not exist. `dataTask` is an asynchronous task. That is, it will run in the background on a different thread. So the order of stuff happening is... 1. start the task. 2. reach the end of the function and return your values (which are still `[:]`) 3. task completes and enters the completion closure. 4. parse the JSON. 5. assign values to `currentObservation` and `currentData`. As you can see here. The order of things happening is not the order in which the lines are written in the code.

Comment: That much I got. My question is how to deal with it? I am a newbie to Swift, Object Oriented design, and multithreading. How do I handle the delay in populating my variables so that I can then use them somewhere else, such as displaying the data, extracting certain data like temperature, etc.? Thanks.